# How can I add an include line to an XKB configuration file?

Tags: xkb

I do which just add a ralt_switch to English(Dvorak-US) keyboard

```
sudo sed -i "249i\    include 'level3(ralt_switch)'" \      
    /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

Restart and you get a non-functional keyboard at login where you cannot type anything. 
You have to fix the file then with Live USB back, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290764/16920) with `chroot`. 
After restart, the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` with much more changes; each environment has now `include 'level3(ralt_switch)'` at the end of their sections

```
66,67d65
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
130,131d127
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
185,186d180
< 
<   include "level3(ralt_switch)"
248d241
<     include 'level3(ralt_switch)'
313,314d305
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
359,360d349
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
600,601d588
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
655,656d641
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
720,721d704
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
787,788d769
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
831,832d811
< 
<    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
851d829
<     include "level3(switch)"
898,899d875
< 
<     include "level3(switch)"
929,930d904
< 
<     include "level3(switch)"
979,980d952
< 
<     include "level3(switch)"
1038,1039d1009
< 
<    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
1102,1103d1071
< 
<    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
1188,1189d1155
< 
<   include "level3(ralt_switch)"
1233,1234d1198
< 
<         include "level3(alt_switch)"
1277,1278d1240
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
1318,1319d1279
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
1365,1366d1324
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
1415,1416d1372
< 
<     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

I generated those lines by

```
sudo sed -i.bak "${pos[1]}i\    include 'level3(ralt_switch)'" /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
```

I am thinking how to double quotes in `include "level...`. Maybe ...

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid

Comment: perhaps your added line should use double-quotes instead of single-quotes, as in the rest of the file.

Comment: @meuh Yes, I did so by `# sudo sed -i.bak "${pos[1]}i\    include 'level3(ralt_switch)'" /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. How can you have there double quotes?

Comment: You just escape them with backslash: `"...\"level3(ralt_switch)\""`.

Comment: @meuh Great! Feel free to make your comment an answer so I remember this mistake better.

Comment: Why are you editing the system files??? Why are you not testing your changes???

Comment: @Gilles I want to have Dvorak with A with dots, ... I think US(English, Dvorak) is best by having German keys under first-level keybinding.  I test them a lot. See here http://askubuntu.com/q/648659/25388 but still unstable.

Comment: @Masi Instead of editing system files, create files in your home directory. And obviously test them *before* logging out.

Comment: And by the way you don't need a live USB to fix those files. If your XKB configuration is so broken that you don't manage to log in in the GUI, you can still log in on a text console.

Comment: @Gilles How can you do it? See the hardware is Macbook Air. I could not login to text console. No Grub found, no recovery mode. I will now try to fix the thing such that I have at least Grub in my system and hopefully recovery mode if it happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer by *meuh*: have double quotes and escape them like

```
sudo sed -i.bak  \
    "${pos[1]}i\ include \"level3(ralt_switch)\"" /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
```