# How to Run `reinstall xkb-data` for Broken Installation in Live USB?

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, x-server

I would like to run the following command for the installation that has broken `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. Editing the file, restarting, just puts the false parameters there back again and again.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data
```

The following methods are just about replacing the file with correct inputs but I cannot get it right.

### Unsuccessful Attempts in Live USB

I do

```
sudo -i 
root@ubuntu~# sudo cp /home/ubuntu/Desktop/file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
```

- also tried `root@ubuntu~# cp /home/ubuntu/Desktop/file /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`
- also tried `root@ubuntu~# cat /home/ubuntu/Desktop/file > /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`
- also tried `root@ubuntu~# sudo cat /home/ubuntu/Desktop/file > /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`
- also tried `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. It says that it saved successfully. Closing window. Seeing it again. No things saved.

Output: no change. Expected result: replacement of the file. 
This method worked first time but not anymore. Doing `gedit .../us` shows the original file, not the new one.

- 3rd iteration i.e. 3rd startup of Live USB on already, to exclude human mistake

If I could login into Ubuntu system and run the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data`, it would solve the problem. 
However, the above method should also work. I do not understand why `write` is occurring.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out the appropriate section by `lsblk`. I did by following [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112358/16920) in the GUI

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/foo
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/foo
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/foo/dev && 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/foo/dev/pts && 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/foo/proc && 
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/foo/sys
sudo chroot /mnt/foo

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data
exit
reboot
```

It works!
I do not understand why I got `initrams` error with persistent live ubuntu in Macbook. Only the default Live Ubuntu worked.